# Gizmos.DrawCube display bug when multiple cubes drawn near each other

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I draw multiple cubes using `Gizmos.DrawCube`to visualize some 3D tiles, I end up with a bunch of cubes inside out. It's called from Editor Code.
Here is the code for the call:

```
private void OnDrawGizmos() {
    foreach (Vector3Int position in positions) {
        Gizmos.DrawCube(position * Const.tileSize, Const.tileVectorSize);
    }
}
```

Here is the display bug:

[image: Display bug]

But everything is ok when _position only contains 1 cube
[image: Everything is ok with only one cube]

Edit: It also happens with few cubes drawn :

[image]

Any idea what is going on and how to correct it ?

Comment: How many cubes are you drawing overall? And does it happen with say 10 cubes? Also asking as some bugs are apparently tied to combined vertices count. (https://answers.unity.com/questions/253121/gizmosdrawcube-bug-doesnt-like-lots-of-calls.html)

Comment: yes, i saw this post, but it seems unrelated as it also happens with few calls. I added a screenshot to illustrate it (only 11 drawn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not actually a bug. The gizmos don't write to the depth buffer. What that means (and what you see in the image) is gizmos being drawn on top of each other regardless of whether they are behind another gizmo. Maybe there is some way to enable depth buffer write or zWrite on gizmos, now you know what to look for. 

 
 What you could do in the meantime is try the [Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm). This is just sorting the gizmos from furthest from the camera to closest before you draw them.

```
private void OnDrawGizmos()
{        
    var sorted = positions.OrderByDescending((x) => Vector3.Distance(Camera.current.transform.position, x));

    foreach (Vector3Int position in sorted)
    {
        Gizmos.DrawCube(position * Const.tileSize, Const.tileVectorSize);
    }
}
```

And this is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Nice! And in case it's not obvious to the asker, a `using System.Linq;` may be required on top of the script.